# “this” keyword doesn’t seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, this

I am trying to understand how the `this` keyword works in JavaScript and I made this script:

```
function click(){
    this.innerHTML="changed";
}
```

Used in this HTML:

```
<button id="clicker" onclick="click()" >Click me</button>
```

But it doesn't work, can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`this` exists only in the scope of the `onclick` event itself. It is not bound automatically to other functions.

Pass it on like this:

```
function click(element){
element.innerHTML="changed";
}
```

and the html:

```
<button id="clicker" onclick="click(this)" >Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You function `click` doesn't know about 'this'. Change it to:

```
function click(elemenet){
    element.innerHTML="changed";
}
```

and

```
<button id="clicker" onclick="click(this)" >Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be about the value of `this`. In an inline handler, `this` will represent the `window`. You can set the value of `this` using `.call()`, so it gives the value you desire.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/5uJ54/

```
<button id="clicker" onclick="click.call(this)" >Click me</button>
```

Now in your `click` method, `this` will be the `<button>` element.

The reason is that your inline attribute gets wrapped in a function, which itself has the context of the element. But it doesn't actually call your function from that context. By doing `click()`, it ends up looking like:

```
function onclick(event) { 
    click();
}
```

Your function is being called against no particular object, so the `window` is implied. By doing:

```
<button id="clicker" onclick="click.call( this )" >Click me</button>
```

...you end up with:

```
function onclick(event) { 
    click.call( this );
}
```

Giving the desired context. You can also pass the event object:

```
<button id="clicker" onclick="click.call( this, event )" >Click me</button>
```

...so you end up with:

```
function onclick(event) { 
    click.call( this, event );
}
```

So now in your `click()` function, you'll have the `event` as you'd expect.

Also, you may have issues with using `click` as a function name. I'd change it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html